# how to pass url with headers to an img tag (src attribute)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api, http-headers

how to pass an url to img tag with **headers**

```
<img src="url" />
```

I didn't try anything yet, I need some alternative solutions, work should be only javascript in front-end part

Comment: What kind of headers?

Comment: any possible headers like key or some authorization anything that the url need

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the security headers, or any other header of the request then browser will not allow you to do that, as headers are treated as unsafe parameter. If you need to download an image from the source where validation is required through headers then your option is to send a spearate ajax request with the security headers, there must be a param that allows include current website cookies as header and most probably it will handle the auth part on the server side. But actually your purpose it not clear, just sentting link with headers to img tag sounds already wrong. If you explain the main purpose maybe we can offer a solution.

P.S.
The same question here have been answered here, if you google 'how to pass url with headers to an img tag' you will see link to stackoverflow as a first result.

Comment: I want to send the `Authorization` header because the image URL is in a private URL.

Comment: You can't do that directly. You can come up with some hacks like catching all image requests with interceptor or something like that and then send the request as ajax and use the response as base64encodedUrl for your images. Or make an endpoint if you have a back end service to catch your requests and send the same request but wiht AUTH headers to the end destination and act like a proxy